# Pandas/NumPy NaN and nan values — how to get a consistent view

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

In DataFrames, depending on the `dtype`, the display of `NaN` value differs:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    "numbers": [1, 3, 4, 5, np.nan],
    "text": ["a", "b", "c", np.nan, "d"]
})
```

[image: DataFrame]

It's just a minor aesthetic issue, but can I print the DataFrame so that the display is consistent as `NaN` also for numbers?

This, in particular, matters when using `to_latex` for publication, and `.to_latex(na_rep="NaN")` does not help.

Comment: Where do you see this difference? Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Yes, also I see the difference when writing in a `.tex` file.

Comment: Can it be a version issue? I see NaN in both columns.

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.18.1 and jupyter notebook 4.2.0 and you?

Comment: Same pandas version but Jupyter Notebook is 4.2.1 (Python 3.5).

Comment: Interesting, in python 2.7 jupyter notebook, it's okay. Seems like a bug. Going to upgrade my jupyter notebook to 4.2.1 now.

Comment: @ayhan Fixed! That was it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Can you please consider deleting question -- its a bug.